# Yii2 AssetBundle Static path

Tags: yii2

I want to include the path of css/js files in service-worker for caching.
what I see Yii deployes css/js files to a dynamic directory using hash in AppAssets.

for example

```
/assets/a7fd2538/css/site.css
```

so is there a way I can disable this hashed directory `a7fd2538`.
and I get just

```
/assets/css/site.css
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your asset files directly to some accessible directory. For example in `web/css/` and `web/js/`. Then you will set your `AppAssets` bundle to use them directly without copying by specifing `$basePath` and `$baseUrl` and leaving `$sourcePath` empty.

For example:

```php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/site.js',
    ];
    // ... other definitions
}
```

Comment: works perfect. so basically not using `$sourcePath` is what is required?

Comment: That and you need to set `$basePath` and `$baseUrl`. When the `$sourcePath` is set the asset manager copies the sources and overwrite `$baseUrl` and `$basePath` so you want to skip that step.